# Why $A_{1k}a_{1l}+\dots+ A_{nk}a_{nl}=0$ when $l\neq k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm reading Smirnov's: *Linear Algebra and Group Theory*. Here:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I know that when $v=k$, it is the determinant (Laplace's expansion). I am trying to verify why $A_{1k}a_{1l}+\dots+ A_{nk}a_{nl}=0$ when $l\neq k$. I have made an example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
{a_{11}}&{a_{12}}&{a_{13}}\\ 
{a_{21}}&{a_{22}}&{a_{23}}\\ 
{a_{31}}&{a_{32}}&{a_{33}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now set $k=2, l=1$ and:

$$A_{12}a_{11}+A_{22}a_{21}+A_{32}a_{31}=\begin{vmatrix}
{a_{21}}&{a_{23}}\\ 
{a_{31}}&{a_{33}}
\end{vmatrix}a_{11}+\begin{vmatrix}
{a_{11}}&{a_{13}}\\ 
{a_{31}}&{a_{33}}
\end{vmatrix}a_{21}+\begin{vmatrix}
{a_{11}}&{a_{13}}\\ 
{a_{21}}&{a_{23}}
\end{vmatrix}a_{31}$$

And then:

$$a_{21}a_{33}a_{11}-a_{31}a_{23}a_{11}+a_{11}a_{33}a_{21}-a_{31}a_{13}a_{21}+a_{11}a_{23}a_{31}-a_{21}a_{13}a_{31}$$

Now:

$$2a_{21}(a_{33}a_{11}-a_{13}a_{31})=2a_{21}(a_{33}a_{11}-a_{13}a_{31})=2a_{21}\begin{vmatrix}
{a_{33}}&{a_{31}}\\ 
{a_{13}}&{a_{11}}
\end{vmatrix}$$

But I don't know why it must equals $0$.  It must be some sort of consequence of determinant multiplication theorems given earlier in the book, but I didn't understand them so well and want to first compute it by hand to obtain some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cofactor is given by $A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j} D_{ij}$ where $D_{ij}$ are the determinants in your expression. Including these signs the terms do cancel. When $k\neq \ell$ then the sum is a detminant of a matrix with two identical columns (the k'th and the $\ell$'th), whence it vanishes.

Comment: Thanks. I did the computation now and it agrees with what is said in the book. And I have noticed my mistake: I was computing the sub-determinant with $A_{i,j}$. I completely forgot the $(-1)^{i+j}$. Silly me.